# Insert characters to end of previous line in Vim

Tags: vim, markdown

I like the Markdown style underlining, but I want it to line up with the above line.

So for example if I have this:

```
heading one
_
^ cursor here
```

I could (in normal mode) just type `(something)i=<ESC><ESC>`, and the result would be:

```
heading one
===========
          ^ cursor here
```

Does anyone know what I can use for `(something)`?

It doesn't really matter to me where my cursor is/ends up, so for example I could be on the last position of the `heading one` line and do some operation to achieve the same result. I'm picky, but not *that* picky.

Comment: I'm surprised none of the markdown plugins support this operation automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use visual selections you can then use `r` to replace every character in said visual selection.

So if you start with your cursor on the "heading one" line type.

```
yypVr=
```

Would copy the line and then replace every character with an equal sign.

Comment: There is always simpler way in vim :). I was going to respond with something like kyypjV:s/./=/g<C-R>$, which is just unnecessarily complicated version of your solution

Answer (score 2):

```
kyypv$r=j
```

- go up one line
- yank it
- paste it below
- visually select the line
- replace every character with `=`

Turn it into a mapping if you ned it often:

```
nnoremap <key> kyypv$r=j
```

I'd suggest you do this on the line to underline itself and not on the line below, though:

```
nnoremap <key> yypv$r=
```